# Flutter - How to get a widget's size after it has been built?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, widget

Suppose I have a list view whose size depends upon the variable no. of itemcount. 
How can I get its height after it has been built? at runtime.

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: index * 12),
              child: UserComment(),
            );
          },
        )
```

Comment: use Layoutbuilder

Comment: as @MinhNguyên said, check this https://youtu.be/IYDVcriKjsw

Comment: Isn't layout builder meant to get the device's constraints? I need a widget's size on the screen.